# If you're not using one of the built-in asynchronous libraries in node, would you use setTimeout to make a function asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have two functions one that I believe is validly synchronous and one that is asynchronous.

**synchronous Function Example**

```
function longProcess() {
    var reps = 5000000000;
    while (reps > 0) {
        reps = reps - 1;
    }
}

var simulateQuery = function(query, callback) {

// simulate a long database query
longProcess();

// return "data" from the simulated query
var data = {name: 'john', age: '44'};

// I'm not going to have error checking in this simulation
var err = null;

// invoke the callback returning err and data as arguments
callback(err, data);
};

console.log('invoking simulateQuery()');

// invoking simulateQuery, with a fake query and a callback function
simulateQuery('{name: john}', function(err, data){
    console.log('simulateQuery() returned with data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});

// Simulate other stuff being done while waiting for query to come back
console.log('other stuff running');
```

Not surprisingly this returns:

1. invoking simulateQuery()
2. <5-6 second wait>
3. simulateQuery() returned with data: {"name":"john","age":"44"}
4. other stuff running

**asynchronous Function Example**

```
function longProcess() {
    var reps = 5000000000;
    while (reps > 0) {
        reps = reps - 1;
    }
}

var simulateQuery = function(query, callback) {

setTimeout(function(){
    longProcess();
    var data = {name: 'john', age: '44'}
    var err = null;
    callback(null, data);
}, 0);

};  

console.log('invoking simulateQuery()');

// invoking simulateQuery, with a fake query and a callback function
simulateQuery('{name: john}', function(err, data){
    console.log('simulateQuery() returned with data: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
});

// Simulate other stuff being done while waiting for query to come back
console.log('other stuff running');
```

This code returns:

- invoking simulateQuery()
- other stuff running
- <5-6 second wait>
- simulateQuery() returned with data: {"name":"john","age":"44"}

My questions are: 1) Is this a valid illustration of a blocking and non-blocking code pattern and 2) why is my callback being fired after the longProcess() function is complete just because I added setTimeout?

Comment: 1. kind of. In the second case the `longProcess` must return immediately to be a better demo. 2. because you're calling it after `longProcess()` is done.

Comment: None of those are really async, but when you use setTimeout, even without a timeout, it removes that code from the current "code block" and adds it to the bottom of the queue instead, and it's executed "when the thread is available" instead of in the normal order.

Comment: @adeneo: "None of those are really async" --- nothing is *really async* in js then. Btw, one must have a clear distinction between `parallel` and `asynchronous`. They are different. And the second example is asynchronous.

Comment: @zerkms - You can't really fake asynchronicity, but ajax, workers, timeouts etc. are async, so in a way using a timeout is async, but here it doesn't really have a timeout (even if there is a minimum), so it just queues the function for whenever the thread is available. A blocking while loop doesn't make it async, only native methods are async. To phrase it more correctly, none of those are non-blocking, the latter one just block at a later time.

Comment: @adeneo: indeed a `longProcess()` is redundant here, but the second solution successfully emulates async code in my opinion. The `simulateQuery`: invokes a callback with results some time later. Thus - I think it's a valid example.

Comment: @zerkms How would you return the longProcess immediately to be a better demo? So is setTimeout somehow changing the execution order(e.g. that min. 10ms delay is allowing other stuff to run).  Does that mean after console.log(other stuff running) is executed my longProcess() function starts blocking again?

Comment: @JohnGalt: it was my misunderstanding. `longProcess` is redundant here.